# Is WCF Chunking Ready For Production Use?

Tags: wcf, chunking

Does anyone know what the status of WCF Chunking?  Is it good for production use? Does anyone have any experience using the new WCF Chunking Channel in production?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717050.aspx

I've downloaded the sample but it seems the API is not ready yet.

Does anyone have any good alternatives to WCF chunking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not an API and it is not part of .NET Framework. It is sample of WCF extensibility.  It is up to you to modify sample if it doesn't fit to your needs. I heard about people who used this code in production.